# how to read html from a url of vue project in python3

Tags: python, html, url

I have a simple Vue project.

HTML content of URL: http://localhost:8080/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>hello-world</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"><style type="text/css">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style></head>
  <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1004.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but hello-world doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"><div data-v-469af010="" class="hello"><h1 data-v-469af010="">Welcome to Your Vue.js App</h1></div></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

I have used this python file to get HTML from the URL.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://localhost:8080')
print(response.text)
```

The output of the python file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>hello-world</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but hello-world doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I am getting `<div id="app"></div>` nothing inside this `div#app`. It should show `<div data-v-469af010="" class="hello"><h1 data-v-469af010="">Welcome to Your Vue.js App</h1>` inside `div#app`.
If I use a simple HTML page then I am getting all HTML content. Is there any solution to get the whole HTML content?